# PHP Post variable not showing

Tags: php, html, vs-web-site-project

I have the following problem. I am  building a website that uses a database. It has simple functions like adding, manipulating and deleting data. I defined an enum in a table in the DB which has these four values
Bachelor of Science,Master of Science,Bachelor of Education,Master of Education. i want the chosen value to be shown in a simple text field. for some reason, even though I'm not using Trim, only the first word is shown. where is the problem?

```
<label> Type of the Course:</label>
        <input input list="courses" name="testType" >
        <datalist id = "courses">
            <option value= "Bachelor of Science">
            <option value= "Master of Science">
            <option value= "Bachelor of Education">
            <option value= "Master of Education">
        </datalist>
            </div>
        <input type="submit" name="submitDep2" class="btn"value="send"/>


    <?php if(isset($_POST['submitDep2'])) {     
                echo $_POST['testType'];?>

            <input type= "text" name="c_type" value= <?php echo $_POST['testType'] ?>>
```

While the first echo shows the whole string, the HTML input only shows "Master" or "Bachelor"

Answer (score 2):

You should put the value between quotes as follows:

```
<input type= "text" name="c_type" value="<?php echo $_POST['testType'] ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the quotes after the value attribute :

```
<input type= "text" name="c_type" value="<?php echo $_POST['testType'] ?>">
```